# What's wrong with this update query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, updates

I'm trying to make a form in a website where you can write the name, price or image of the product you want to update and in the textbox next to every field you can write the new value you want it to take but idk why everytime I write something the only field that updates is the name and instead of change the former name for the new one it change to 0, the php code I'm using is this:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","paradise_root","gantzminus1");
mysql_select_db("paradise_dbsalon");
$nombre = $_POST['txtnombre']; 
$precio = $_POST['txtprecio'];  
$imagen = $_POST['txtimagen'];
$nombre2 = $_POST['txtnombre2']; 
$precio2 = $_POST['txtprecio2'];  
$imagen2 = $_POST['txtimagen2'];

$_GUARDAR_SQL = "update productosyservicios set nombre = ('".$nombre2."') or precio = ('".$precio2."') or imagen = ('".$imagen2."') where nombre = ('".$nombre."') or precio= ('".$precio."') or imagen = ('".$imagen."') "; 

$rst = mysql_query($_GUARDAR_SQL) or die("error".$_GUARDAR_SQL); 
if($rst==true){
$rest=false;

}
?>
```

Comment: not sure what u are trying to achieve but the query for sure is not correct. Could u explain a bit  on what u are trying to do ?

Comment: You can't set a value using or statements, `set nombre = ('".$nombre2."') or precio = ('".$precio2."') or imagen = ('".$imagen2."')` is flawed you may mean `set nombre = ('".$nombre2."'), precio = ('".$precio2."'), imagen = ('".$imagen2."')`  but I'm not sure given I don't know if you want to update all 3 if any of the values is true.

Comment: ok imagine that you got a table with name, price and image fields then you want to update a row from your website I'm trying to make that when you write for example cheese in a textbox and in the next one I write banana the name in that row change from cheese to banana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this gona be with multiple CASE :

Try that:

```
UPDATE productosyservicios SET 
nombre = CASE WHEN nombre = '".$nombre."' then '".$nombre2."' else nombre   END ,
precio = CASE WHEN precio = '".$precio."' then '".$precio2."' else precio   END ,
imagen = CASE WHEN imagen = '".$imagen."' then '".$imagen2."' else imagen   END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GUARDAR_SQL = "update productosyservicios set nombre = ('".$nombre2."'), precio = ('".$precio2."'), imagen = ('".$imagen2."') where nombre = ('".$nombre."') or precio= ('".$precio."') or imagen = ('".$imagen."') ";
```

You had `or` in your UPDATE

```
(UPDATE productosyservicios set nombre = something **OR** <- this shouldnt be or it should be a comma
```

updates should be seperated by commas

Comment: I changed it but now it deletes nombre and imagen and transform precio to 0

Comment: we cant see what you are posting unfortunately -> my guess is you are either posting them in the wrong order (i.e. `$nombre2` should be part of your `WHERE` clause, not the update item) or something is going wrong with the post itself and some data is not being transmitted (which is normally a mis-named variable / form field)

Comment: I'm sure the names of the fields are right and also I think I'm doing it right cause nombre, precio or imagen are the names of the fields I want to change and nombre2, precio2 or imagen2 are the new values so it should be like that or am I wrong?

Comment: Will you always be posting changes to nombre, precio and imagen?? If you are only posting one change then it needs a different query

Answer (score 0):

Your query is off.

```
$_GUARDAR_SQL = "UPDATE productosyservicios SET nombre = '".$nombre2."', precio = '".$precio2."', imagen = '".$imagen2."' WHERE nombre = '".$nombre."' OR precio = '".$precio."' OR imagen = '".$imagen."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is very bad (not correct).

You must change to:

```
$_GUARDAR_SQL = "update productosyservicios set nombre = '".$nombre2."' , precio = '".$precio2."' , imagen = '".$imagen2."' where nombre = '".$nombre."' or precio= '".$precio."' or imagen = '".$imagen."' ";
```

I'm not sure for your where clauses.

Also check your database. Somewhere you can have integer column for text - change to varchar for all texts.

Comment: I changed it but now it deletes nombre and imagen and transform precio to 0 and the text columns are varchar